# Can't find JButton class with OpenJDK 6 and 7

Tags: swing, ubuntu-12.04, java

I'm trying to install Java on my Ubuntu 12.04 machine and I'm frustrated, to say the least.  I have OpenJDK/JRE 6 and 7 installed, but the following code won't find the JButton or JFrame classes:

```
package app;

import java.awt.*;

public class AppInterface {

    private JFrame main;
    private JButton play;
    private JButton exit;

}
```

I have all of the relevant libraries installed from apt-get.  Why's missing that I don't have access to Swing libraries?

My compile errors:

```
`Have no file for /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-i386/jre/lib/netx.jar`
`Have no file for /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-i386/jre/lib/plugin.jar`
`Have no file for /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-i386/jre/lib/jfr.jar`
```

Comment: JButton is a swing component. The Button in awt is just called Button.

Comment: The interface should be defined as `interface` or `abstract class` not a `class` .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should `import javax.swing.*;` as well.

Comment: Thanks much.  I was seeing javax as being below java.awt. in my documentation.